# Find if a value is not present in array of objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to check if a field is not present in an array of objects.
Let's say I have an array inside documents called attributes:

```
[
  {
    attributes: [
      {
        name: "Cool",
        value: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I wish to find items which are unspecified. I will use an $or operator to find empty values

```
$attributes: {
    $elemMatch: {
        $or: [
           { name: 'cool', value: '' },
           { name: 'cool', value: { $exists: false } },

           { name: {ne: 'cool' } ?????
        ]
    }
}
```

But I want to find items where {name: 'Cool'} just isn't in the array and I can't figure out the syntax.

Any help would be great, many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `$ne` usage will suffice outside an `$elemMatch` expression, Mongo "flattens" arrays for most queries so if a single element in the array matches the query it suffices the conditions.

In your case if you use `$ne` and `cool` is one of the elements then the condition will be "matched" and the document excluded, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  "attributes.name": {
    $ne: "Cool"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oriyr9LJZqi)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar use case where any element in the array is not matching with the searched value. So, I am extending the answer to this question.

> If you specify a single query predicate in the
> $elemMatch
> expression, and are not using the $not or $ne operators inside of
> $elemMatch
> ,
> $elemMatch
> can be omitted. [reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#std-label-elemmatch-single-query-condition)

```
db.collection.find({
  "attributes": {
    $elemMatch: {
       "name": {
          $ne: "Cool"
        }
    }
  })
```

This query returns the documents where **any name in the results array** is not "Cool".

```
db.collection.find({
  "attributes.name": {
    $ne: "Cool"
  }
})
```

This query returns the documents where **all of the name in the results array** are not "Cool".